# Random string generator segmentation fault

Tags: c++, linux, string, debugging, segmentation-fault

I have an exercise in which I made a function that generates a random string ! When I run the program in Windows it works fine , but when I try to run the same program in linux I get a segmentation fault. I did a debugging in linux 
and I go this :

** Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x08048be5 in get_unique_name() () **

The code of get_unique_name()

```
/*Function that generates random strings*/
string get_unique_name( ) 
{
  char* s ;          
  for (int i = 0; i < 3 ; ++i) 
  {
     int randomChar = rand()%(26+26+10);
     if (randomChar < 26)
         s[i] = 'a' + randomChar;
     else if (randomChar < 26+26)
         s[i] = 'A' + randomChar - 26;
     else
         s[i] = '0' + randomChar - 26 - 26;
}
 s[3] = 0;
 return s ;
}
```

Comment: Hi. Your dynamic array is not allocated. Your error basically means that you are trying to access memory which not available to you. Take a look here, for example: http://web.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/C_arrays.html

Answer (score 0):

You don't initialize `s` pointer.

using array solves your issue:

```
 char s[4];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char* s;
```

is uninitialized pointer. Dereferencing it is undefined behavior. The return type of the function is (`std::`)`string`, so `s` should be `std::string`, too:

```
std::string s(3, ' '); // ' ' is a dummy character
// you could also do
std::string s;
s.resize(3);
```

And `s[3] = 0;` won't be needed (needs to be removed).

Answer (score 0):

s is a pointer which needs to point to some location in memory. You can then store some data (bits) in this memory location. Just defining (char *s) a pointer doesn't by itself allocate memory that the pointer points to, you need to explicitly make the pointer to point to a memory location that you must first allocate dynamically (malloc/calloc/new etc) or statically for ex. s[10] like other folks have suggested.

Now you may ask, why did it work on Windows ?
to which I would say, purely by luck ...